# GWT: FileUpload Browse Button styling

Tags: css, gwt, file-upload

I need to style the browse button of file upload in GWT.... I found the way through this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/15621-styling-a-file-browse-button/. But I am not able to use the same in GWT. Any idea how to go about it?.

I am using GWT 2.4.0

Comment: There is already a Proper Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309106/file-upload-control-and-gwt-look-and-feel But i think you can try the following. This helped me to overcome the fault. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html **OR** http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the following approach and it worked for me.

I hid the file upload field and used a trigger box on the screen instead. Trigger box click is delegated back to file upload browse button click using JSNI approach

```
private static native void fileClick (Element el) /*-{

             el.click();

 }*-/;
```

And used the fileupload.getfilename() and set the trigger text box with file location details.