# How to display HTML "file" fields normally in Google Chrome?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

There is a `PHP` file containing a formulaire `<form` which contains a `file` field :

`<input type="file" name="doc_fichier" maxlength="255" size="50">` .

When I open the page with `Firefox` then the field is well displayed as shown in this captured image :

[image]

But when I open the page with `Google Chrome` then I got this :

[image]

So how to do so that `Google Chrome` displays the element correctly ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309106/file-upload-control-and-gwt-look-and-feel

Comment: There is no duplicate : I didn't post it in other tags !

Comment: The content of the question is an exact duplicate; this is about the implementation of file input elements in different browsers. The use of PHP is irrelevant, as is the UI language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "correctly" way to display a file field, it is browser-dependant.

Your screenshot is the standart way of displaying a file field in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/ajaxray/bootstrap-file-field

This tiny plugin will display the file input field as a bootstrap button (with configurable classes), similar in all browser and will show selected file names (or selection errors) beautifully.

Additionally you can set various restrictions using simple data-attributes or JS settings. e,g, `data-file-types="image/jpeg,image/png"` will restrict selecting file types except jpg and png images.